# NODEJS + WS LIBRARY = BUFFER ALLOC ERROR

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, buffer

We are building a simple express + websocket library (ws).
When we run a simple example like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

//initialize a simple http server
const server = http.createServer(app);

//initialize the WebSocket server instance
const wss = new WebSocket.Server( server );

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

    //connection is up, let's add a simple simple event
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

        //log the received message and send it back to the client
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        ws.send('Hello, you sent -> '+ message);
    });

    //send immediatly a feedback to the incoming connection    
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

//start our server
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8999, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port'+ server.address().port + ' 
:)');
});
```

But when we run the app, we got this error:

```
ws constants.js:8 EMPTY_BUFFER: Buffer.alloc(0), ^ TypeError: 
Buffer.alloc is not a function
```

Do you know what is it about? Google points in several cases due to versions conflicts.
If I type: nodejs -v it trows me: v 4.2.6

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I already find the problem... It was a packages version problem.

I uninstall everything, and reinstall everything about nodejs with this line:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I ugraded to nodejs 8.x. After that, restarted my session, everything worked.
Later I found some comments about the right version to use WS library.

Regards!